# Scala Gatling POST after GET doesn't work

Tags: scala, gatling

I learing garling framework for load testing and I have problem with send POST request with json body after GET redirect, second request return status 400. Part with sending POST without GET work properly. Anyone have idea why it doesn't work?

```
var token: String = ""
var tokenJson: String = ""
val scn2 = scenario("SCENARIO2")
.exec(http("open")
  .get("/core/auth")
  .check(status.is(302))
  .check(header("Location").saveAs("url")))
.exec(session => {
  token = session.get("url").as[String].split("/").last
  tokenJson = """{"token":"""" + token + """"}"""
  print(tokenJson)
  session
}).pause(1 second)
.exec(http("openPOST")
  .post("/core/init").header("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .body(StringBody(tokenJson)).asJSON
  .check(status.is(200))
  .check(jsonPath("$.basketToken").saveAs("basketToken")))
.exec(session => {
  val basketToken = session.get("basketToken").as[String]
  println("BasketToken " + basketToken.orElse("nothing"))
  session
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by this

```
StringBody(session => tokenJson)
```